# Concurrency Problem: how to have only one thread go through critical section

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to have a multithreaded function that allocates some memory for an object `obj` and returns the allocated memory. My current single-threaded and multiple threaded version codes are below.

The multi-threaded version has no race conditions but runs slow when a lot of threads are trying to get the lock. After the `malloc` and pointer update, each thread still needs to acquire and release the same lock. That causes some multi-threading performance drop. I wonder if there are some other ways to improve performance.

```c
struct multi_level_tree{
    multi_level_tree* ptr[256];
    mutex mtx;
};

multi_level_tree tree; // A global object that every thread need to access and update

/* Single Threaded */
multi_level_tree* get_ptr(multi_level_tree* cur, int idx) {
    if (!cur[idx].ptr) 
        cur[idx].ptr = malloc(sizeof(T));
    return cur[idx].ptr;
}

/* Multi Threaded with mutex */
void get_ptr(multi_level_tree* cur, int idx) {
    if (!cur[idx].ptr) {
        cur[idx].mtx.lock(); // other threads wait here, and go one by one
        /* Critical Section Start */
        if (!cur[idx].ptr)
            cur[idx].ptr = malloc(sizeof(multi_level_tree)); // malloc takes a while
        /* Critical Section End */
        cur[idx].mtx.unlock();
    }
    return cur[idx].ptr;
}
```

The code I am looking for should have the following property.

- When the first thread allocated the memory, it should alert all other threads waiting for it.
- All other threads should be unblocked at the same time.
- No race condition.

**The challenges in the problem**
 * The tree is sparse with multiple levels, initialize all of it is impossible considering the memory we have
 * Similar to [Double-Checked Locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) problem, but was trying to avoid `std::atomic`

The point for this code is to implement a multi-level array as a global variable. Except for the lowest level, each array is a list of pointers to the next level array. Since this data structure needs to grow dynamically, I got into this problem.

Comment: why do all threads have to use the same ressource to allocate memory? Cant they each work on their own?

Comment: That is the point I am asking. The resource `obj` is actually a global multi-level array.  All threads want to access and update the data structure. @formerlyknownas_463035818

Comment: not sure, but I think your multithreaded isnt really threadsafe due to accessing `!o.ptr` before locking the mutex.

Comment: I dont see the bigger picture, so I can just ask questions... you know that `malloc` merely allocates memory, but does not create objects?

Comment: I think the fundamental problem is that _many_ threads are accessing _one_ exclusive ressource, which will cause a bottleneck. I too don't see, why you would want to allocate memory in this way. Could you please elaborate _why_ you are doing this? The code you described below you actual code seems to be way better, what is the problem with implemting this?

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://preshing.com/20130930/double-checked-locking-is-fixed-in-cpp11/

Comment: That is because of performance issues. The common case is that o.ptr is set up. In that case, no lock is needed and works pretty fast. But I have to have a second if-statement to prevent the second thread from overwriting the pointer.

Comment: @WilliamClements This looks promising. Although requiring a lot of change to my code, `std::atomic` can definitely be used in my code. I was wondering if any solutions with semaphores and counters would solve this problem more elegantly.

Comment: How about something like `struct obj { T object; };` and not even need mutex or dynamic allocation?

Comment: Side note: You ,may find `std::scoped_lock` helpful in managing your mutex.

Comment: Do you need to deallocate the memory, or is it just one time allocated?

Comment: Deallocation occurs rarely during execution. When I try to remove a node, I deallocate its children recursively. The major time for deallocation is when program exit. I recursively remove all the nodes. @JoachimIsaksson

Comment: Why are you using `malloc()`? Why does your code not require casting the result of it to the target pointer type? Why are you assigning to `!expression`? These things make me wonder what the real code looks like. Please extract and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment form @WilliamClements , I see this is a double-checked locking problem itself. The original multi-threading code in my question may broke. To program it correctly, I switched to atomic pointers to prevent ordering problems with load/store instructions.

However, the example still uses a lock that I want to get rid of. Therefore, I choose to use `std::atomic::compare_exchange_weak` to only update the pointer when its value is nullptr. In this way, only one thread will successfully update the pointer value, and other threads are going to release requested memory if they fail `std::atomic::compare_exchange_weak`.

This code is doing very well for me so far.

```
struct multi_level_tree{
    std::atomic<multi_level_tree*> ptr;
};

multi_level_tree tree; 

void get_ptr(multi_level_tree* cur, int idx) {
    if (!cur[idx].ptr.load()) { 
        /* Critical Section Start */
        if (!cur[idx].ptr.load()) {
            node* tmp = malloc(sizeof(multi_level_tree)*256);
            if (cur[idx].ptr.compare_exchange_weak(nullptr, tmp)) {
                /* successfully updated, do nothing */
            }
            else {
                /* Already updated by other threads, release */
                free(tmp);
            }
        }
        /* Critical Section End */
    }
    return cur[idx].ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> how to have only one thread go through critical section

You could use a mutex. There's an example in your question.

It is not the most optimal solution for synchronised innitialisation. A simple improvement is to use a local static, in which case compiler is responsible for implementing the synchronisation:

```
T& get_T() {
    static T instance;
    return instance;
}
```

> but runs slow when a lot of threads are trying to get the lock

This problem is inherent with serialising the access to the same data structure. A way to improve performance is to avoid doing that in the first place.

In this particular example, it appears that you could simply initialise the resource while the process is still single threaded, and start the parallel threads only after the initialisation is complete. That way no locking is required to access the pointer.

If that is not an option, another approach is to simply call `get_ptr` once in each thread, and store a copy locally. That way the locking overhead remains minimal.

Even better would be to have separate data structures in each thread. This is useful when threads only produce data, and don't need to access results from other threads.

---

Regarding edited example: You might benefit from a lock free tree implementation. It may be difficult to implement however.

Comment: I found this true for the singleton model. However, it cannot easily adapts to my problem because I am a tree structure, with each level containing more nodes to the next level. I need a dynamic array for each tree node.

Comment: True. But I am implementing a 8-level tree. The constructor should only initialize the root node with nullptr.

Comment: @BruceShen Why not initialise the entire tree immediately?

Comment: 8-level tree with 256 child each node would take all 64-bit addresses in the bottom level. Trying to create shadow memory that gives each address metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot easily fix it, since it's inherent of concurrency, i have an idea that may improve or decrease performance rather substantially, through.

If this resource is really used that often and is detrimental you could try to use Active Object (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object) and Boost Lockfree Queue (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/lockfree/reference.html#header.boost.lockfree.queue_hpp). Use atomic store/load on Future objects, and you will make this process completely lockless. But on the other hand it will require a single thread to maintain. Performance of such solution depends heavily on how often is this resource used.

Comment: Really appreciate it. I think I got an idea using atomic load and store and `atomic::compare_exchange`. I will post in another answer for proofreading.